# Is the inequality solution below legal?

Tags: limits, inequality

First of all, I know this is very basic, but I've taken a big break from University for personal reasons and I've forgotten a lot of basic math. I've been doing the practice problems in the Calculus textbook. Here's the problem:

> Prove that $$ \lim_{x \to 1}(5x-3)=2 $$ using the strict limit
>   definition $$0<|x-x_0|<δ , |f(x)-L|<ε$$
>   where $δ$, $ε$ are positive numbers.

The writer uses the $ε$ part, advancing it and getting to the point where $$|x-1|<ε/5$$
All fine to that point. But then, he says that since $|x-1|$ is also less than $δ$, we can safely assume that $δ=ε/5$. I honestly don't see how that is legal. I am obviously missing something crucial here, but I don't see how we can assume that since a number is smaller than two other positive numbers, the two positive numbers are equal.

I hope I explained my problem well. This is my first question here, and I did my best with formatting, but please excuse any possible mistakes. I also skipped the calculations to get into the root of the problem faster.

Answer (score 2):

The author wrote the idea badly. What s/he should have said:

Now, it is clear that if we let our $\delta$ be $\epsilon/5$ and assume $|x - 1| < \delta$, then the desired result holds, since:

\begin{align}
|f(x) - 2| &= |(5x - 3) - 2| \\
&= |5x-5| \\
&= 5|x-1| \\
&< 5\frac{\epsilon}{5} \\
&= \epsilon
\end{align}

For what it's worth, you expressed your question very well. :)